# String array doesn't show all values correctly in android

Tags: android, arrays, xml, string, android-resources

I'm making a E-commerce app, which has a brand list to choose from to filter the products, I'm saving all the brands in arrays.xml inside string array, but some of the strings shows as white spaces at runtime just like the screenshot, and when I click on this white space value it shows value correctly, I don't understand and searched for similar issue but couldn't find anything

[image]
[image]

Here's a sample of my brand_list in strings.xml and the same in strings.xml(ar-rEG)

```xml
    <string-array name="brand_list">
        <item>الكل</item>
        <item>212</item>
        <item>Acm</item>
        <item>Anivagene</item>
        <item>Balea</item>
        <item>Bioblas</item>
        <item>BioGroup</item>
        <item>Breeze</item>
        <item>Exaggerate</item>
        <item>Exfoliate</item>
        <item>Farm Stay</item>
        <item>Fresh Talk</item>
        <item>Isis</item>
        <item>Kolagra</item>
        <item>Mash</item>
        <item>Melatex</item>
        <item>OGX</item>
        <item>Olay</item>
        <item>Rionire</item>
        <item>Sessa</item>
        <item>Si</item>
    </string-array>
```

**StoreHomeFragment**

```
    private lateinit var brandAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Rest of the code
        brandAdapterImpl()
    // Rest of the code
    
    // Setting brand adapter ready.
    private fun brandAdapterImpl() {
        brandAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
            requireActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            resources.getStringArray(R.array.brand_list)
        )
        // Setting the adapter to brandAdapter and observe the selected brand for any future changes.
        binding.autoCompleteBrand.run {
            setAdapter(brandAdapter)
            viewModel.selectedBrandPosition.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                setText(brandAdapter.getItem(it), false)
                isSaveEnabled = false
                freezesText = false
            }
        }
        // When choosing item from the brandList save it into liveData in the viewModel.
        binding.autoCompleteBrand.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
            val brand = brandAdapter.getItem(position)
            viewModel.saveSelectedBrand(brand!!, position)
            viewModel.filterProducts()
        }
    }
```

**Here is what I have tried:**

-Changed the size of the string array to be smaller.

-Changed the string array to be array

-Deleted the arabic and left only english brand as it's might be the 2 languages

-Put the brand list inside string.xml and string.xml (ar - rEG)

Comment: Try to add your code to the question. This may help other developers to better find an answer to your issue.

Comment: thanks @gioravered , I've edited the question you can check it and see if there anything would help

Comment: Have you tried other layout options besides `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`? It is much better to create your custom ArrayAdapter since I believe that adapter hasn't been maintained well.

Comment: When you check the list, are values really missing or there is just a big space between some values? If values are missing, is it always the same ones?

Comment: Values are missing, and if you pressed on this white space it shows the value in edittext correctly, It's not always the same it varies when you choose a value but still most of them are the same, specially the arabic ones in the bottom of the string array @gioravered

Comment: Yes tried a custom layout and the same issue remains @LawrenceGimenez

Comment: You mean implementing your own Adapter? And inflating your own layout? You should more info to your question. What AS version are you using? The compileSdk version?

Comment: Actually no I was using ArrayAdapter class, but I've tried a custom adapter now and nothing changed, also my custom layout, but there's something new noticed, when I'm trying to use .sorted() method the list suppose to sort english strings first then the arabic, it really shows all the english values but when it comes to arabic values they all whitespaced.
when tried to use sortedDecending() method it shows white spaces randomly.
I'm using android studio dolphin and the compileSdk 33 @LawrenceGimenez

Comment: I've tried the emulator with sorted() method but white spaces shows randomly not like my phone with arabic values only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all about the layout, I've used ArrayAdapter and the

```
android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line
```

So the only difference is in declaring brandAdapter:

```
brandAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
        requireActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
        resources.getStringArray(R.array.brand_list)
    )
```

The list now is showns all the values in the array whether it was arabic or english.